# Laravel app.js defer is not loading before content

Tags: javascript, laravel, node-modules

I am trying to add jquery and use into a new project

app.js

```
require('./custom');
require('./bootstrap');
require('alpinejs');
```

custom.js

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
window.Swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

guest.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
            {{ $slot }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<x-guest-layout>
    <script>
        function alerta() {//This Work
            Swal.fire("Hello World Sweetalert2");//This Work
            $('.lol').hide();//This Work
        }

        $(function() {//$ This not Work
            console.log( "ready!" );
        });
        Swal.fire("Hello World Sweetalert2");//This not Work
    </script>
    <x-jet-button onclick="alerta()" class="lol">Alert</x-jet-button>
</x-guest-layout>
```

And finally get the error *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined* or *Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined*

How can i solve this?

Edit:
Thanks to @Areg this question is solved, I understood this better after reading [The Script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: can you share the package.json file

Comment: your script tag in welcome.blade.php is loading before the `defer`ed app script is loaded. Try to use js only in js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write something into app.js you need to compile it later on using `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`. Also don't defer you app js file, because it  is designed to run the script after the document is loaded as it states on w3schools

`The defer attribute is a boolean attribute.`

`When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.`

`Note: The defer attribute is only for external scripts (should only be used if the src attribute is present).`

Comment: @NICO why he should use defer if he wants the script to run before the page?

Comment: @NICO you didn't read it fully, there's actually two points are missing. And still if he will remove the defer it will work because again as he pointed out `welcome.blade.php is loading before the defered app`

Comment: @NICO THat's exactly what i am telling thats why you need to remove defer

Comment: thanks, it works! I understood this better after reading [The Script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), Thanks for your help!! +1

Comment: @JhordyBarrera mind choosing it as the correct answer, just in case if someone else stumbles upon this aswell